# Library load not extending to functions in Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, scope, sparkr

I have a SparkR script that loads some libraries, and also defines functions from other sourced scripts. The head of it looks like this:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"))) 
library(devtools)   
library(JC.utilities)         # user-created

source("path/to/clean_data.R")
```

where `clean_data.R` uses some functions found in the `JM.utilities` library, like this:

```
clean_data <- function(df) {
  ... 
  return(JC.utilities::reformat(df))
}
```

In base R, this is no problem, since by sourcing the R script in which this function is defined should mean that the library and the function are now in the same scope. But in Spark, I get this error message when I call `clean_data()`:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘JM.utilities’
```

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't Spark seem to remember that I've already loaded this library?
2. Is there a way around this issue without having to define a bunch of things explicitly?

Comment: 1) Are you running this locally or on YARN?  2) Try running `clean_data` from the same script where you load `SparkR` and `JC.utilities` (i.e. without sourcing a separate script); are you still getting the error?

Comment: 1) Running on Yarn. 2) Same issue occurs when scripts are run directly instead of sourced. I think discovered how to fix this, however. Will post about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loaded the library on the driver, but not on the executors that are working on separate workspaces.

You need to import JC.utilities within the function that you apply to your dataframe.

If the library is not installed at all on the executors, you will need to do it or you may try doing [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/105781/using-r-packages-with-sparkr-3.html).

I devised a minimal example to illustrate my point with the library stringr and its function str_length:

```
> d<-data.frame(a=c("a", "abcd", "bb"), b=c(1,2,3))
> df <- as.DataFrame(d)
```

Let's try dapply to see that it works with base R code:

```
> dapplyCollect(df, function(x) {cbind(x$a, x$b, x$b*x$b+1) })
    [,1]   [,2] [,3] 
[1,] "a"    "1"  "2"  
[2,] "abcd" "2"  "5"  
[3,] "bb"   "3"  "10"
```

It works! Then let's try to count the number of characters of the 1st column (I could use nchar but the idea is to demonstrate how to use a library).

```
> import(stringr)
> str_length("abcdef")
[1] 4
```

It works fine in the driver. Let's try with spark:

```
> dapplyCollect(df, function(x) {cbind(x$a, x$b, x$b*x$b+1, str_length(x$a)) })
17/11/08 18:55:17 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in cbind(x$a, x$b, x$b * x$b + 1, str_length(x$a)) : 
  could not find function "str_length"
```

As I explained, importing the library in the driver does not import it in the workers. Yet that's where I need it. Let's now import the library within dapply:

```
> dapplyCollect(df, function(x) {library(stringr); cbind(x$a, x$b, x$b*x$b+1, str_length(x$a)) })
     [,1]   [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"    "1"  "2"  "1" 
[2,] "abcd" "2"  "5"  "4" 
[3,] "bb"   "3"  "10" "2"
```

And there you go.

Comment: This is not correct - I have submitted [SparkR scripts to YARN](https://www.nodalpoint.com/sparkr-in-cloudera-hadoop/) with neither `SparkR` nor other packages used (namely `magrittr`) being installed in the cluster workers

Comment: The page says that R needs to be installed however. This is because when you apply R code to the rows of your dataframe, the workers are in charge of doing it, using R. If the R code you execute on the rows depends on a library, you need that library to be imported on the workers.

Comment: This worked for me. It was an issue with how I was loading in my libraries. Needed to include ```.libPaths("./myRLibs") ``` in my ```dapply``` function, and add this flag when starting Spark: ```--archives myRLibs.tar.gz#myRLibs```

Comment: I added a minimal example to illustrate all this.

Comment: Is this topic spark version related? Did it changed lately?

Comment: No, the problem is not related to any specific version. In spark, when you use a library in a transformation (UDF), it needs to be visible to the code being executed inside the executors.

Comment: I have two docker image, tested, one works, the other not (new). Libraries are installed on the new one and `.libPaths(..)` shows the correct location. What does visible mean? I would ask question, but there is no way I get is right on SO.  [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401394/5770014) :)

Comment: What do you mean by new? Visible means installed and imported. Importing the lib within the function is probably not the best way by the way but to be honest, I am not a specialist of sparkR.